# Is it possible to use Back in Time with Ubuntu One without storing the back up files locally?

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, backup

I use Deja Dup as my back up tool. Love its simplicity and the fact that I can store my back up directly on my Ubuntu One account.
Now I really like the flexibility of Back in Time, but I can not find a clean way to store my back up in Ubuntu One. Some threads suggest to use the Ubuntu One folder in your system, and that works, but it also keeps a local copy of the back up in my system, and I do not want that.

Any work around for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that it's currently possible to configure Back In Time to save the backups anywhere other than a folder on the filesystem (Deja Dup is able to back up to other places, as you know, such as Ubuntu One).

(warning: super techie stuff ahead)

It might be possible to back up to Ubuntu One with Back In Time by mounting your Ubuntu One storage as a folder -- doing this would require someone writing something like a fuse filesystem or mountable server using the Ubuntu One files APIs, which as far as I'm aware no-one's done, and I personally would be very worried about trusting my backups to such a setup -- what happens if your broadband dies halfway through a backup taking place? Without some cooperation from the backup tool itself (B.I.T. in this case) you'd need to be very careful. If the Back In Time development team are interested in making Ubuntu One a backup target then I (as head of U1's app developer programme) am more than happy to chat to them about how they might go about it! Failing that, though, I'd stick with Deja Dup for now to back up to Ubuntu One if I were you :)

Comment: Thx for your comments. Pretty much what I guessed. I asked a question in lanuchpad at the BIT section to see if they plan to implement this feature. No response so far. Deja Dup is OK, I can even suspend my laptop in the middle of a back up to U1 and will resume it afterwards. It just lacks configuration for my taste, like scheduling of back ups. Anyway, keep up the good work in U1! Looking forward to see more features (contacts sync, notes, thunderbird, etc...)